# Suppose $f : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and not bounded above or below. Show $f(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$

Tags: analysis, continuity

I.E that the range of $f$ is the entire set $\mathbb{R}$

thanks

Comment: Use the intermediate value theorem. You can do it.

Comment: Maybe this is nitpicking, but shouldn the question be more correctly like: Suppose a function f from the reals to the reals is continuous and not bounded above AND below. Show $f(R)=R$? Otherwise: $f(x)=e^x$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 $e^x$ is not onto!

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal Indeed, it is not onto, and that's why it serves as counterexample as Quickbeam2k1 argues.

Comment: I agree with @Quickbeam2k1.

Comment: I am only nitpicking about the "OR" and "AND" from the logic point of view. As the question is posed, the case that the function is only one bounded from below is still alowed. Thus you can not prove the claim.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen does this look promising: IVT can only be used on closed bounded intervals so consider [a,b] where a,b are reals and f is cts on this interval. Then by IVT, if f(a)<g<f(b) we must have c st f(c)=g. Now, since a,b are arbitrary real numbers we can always 'move' the interval along R to find unique values of f in R, eventually we get that range of f must be R. Sorry this is not very nice, but along the right lines?

Comment: @Marc Van Leeuwen what do you think?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1: Your nitpicking is out of place for this perfectly clear natural language construct. If I would say "I did not break the object intentionally or accidentally", then nobody would construe that to mean "either I did not break the object intentionally, or I did not break the object accidentally" (which would be a tautology). Your interpretation of the title is doing just that. The obvious interpretation is: $f$ is _neither_ bounded above _nor_ bounded below".

Comment: @Sidrow: I don't understand your formulation. For any given $y$ there are $a$ with $f(a)>y$ (since $f$ is not bounded above by $y$) and $b$ with $f(b)<y$ (since $f$ is not bounded below by $y$). Now you can apply the IVT on the interval $[a,b]$ or $[b,a]$ (whichever has its bounds in the right order). That's all there is to it.

Comment: @Marc van Leeuwen. I don't agree completely. It is only clear what is meant, since we got the additional information: Show $f(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$. However, you are right that my comment is potentially a bit out of place. Nevertheless, I think it is good to be precise when you start to learn mathematics as the OP obviously does. This may help in later studies.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen So we know for f(a)<f(b) say, there exists c in (a,b) such that f(c)=g where f(a)<g<f(b). But then surely we would get y<f(a)<g<f(b)<y which doesn't make sense. Any help?

Comment: @Sidrow. I chose $a,b$ such that $f(a)>y>f(b)$, so assuming $f(a)<f(b)$ is what makes no sense. In the IVT the intermediate value $g$ is _given_ and $c$ is then produced by the theorem. Take $g=y$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $y\notin f\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ for some $y\in\mathbb R$.

Then $\mathbb{R}=U\cup V$
for $U:=f^{-1}\left(-\infty,y\right)$ and
$V:=f^{-1}\left(y,\infty\right)$. The sets $U,V$ are disjoint and open as preimages
of open sets under a continuous function. Also both sets are not empty
since $f$ is not bounded above *and* is not bounded below (my interpretation of your question).

That means that
$\mathbb{R}$ is not connected wich is not true. So hypothese $y\notin f\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$
must be wrong and we are allowed to conclude that $y\in f(\mathbb R)$ for each $y\in\mathbb R$.